# Including Wordpress functions

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to run an external php file in wordpress that will be able to use all the WP's tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should just  include the wp-blog-header.php file at the top of the PHP file.

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-blog-header.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Load `wp-load.php` to include all the Wordpress functions.

However, beware of [bugs](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11549).